# AVAudioSession outputVolume not updating on iOS 9+

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I activated the audio session on view load (There isn't an error when activating the audio session):

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];`

I'm accessing the output volume with:

`[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] outputVolume]`

The issue I'm finding is that the output volume returns only the initial device volume. If I mute or change the device volume, outputVolume only returns the initial volume. Example: I activate the session with the volume at 0.062500. I mute the device, outputVolume still returns 0.062500. If I change the volume to max volume, outputVolume still returns 0.062500.

Note: This issue is happening on iOS 9+. iOS 8 doesn't seem to have this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVAudioSession's OutputVolume never changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872409/avaudiosessions-outputvolume-never-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because WKWebView is considered a different process. To fix this issue, I needed to set the category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord with option AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers. In [Setting AVAudioSession Category has no effect on sound from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152211/setting-avaudiosession-category-has-no-effect-on-sound-from-wkwebview), the answer by Piet had the solution I needed.