# WkWebView momentarily disabled when CrossSimpleAudioPlayer plays

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have a WkWebView loaded with a `<video>` and when I use CrossSimpleAudioPlayer in the C# code, the webview goes black, the CrossSimpleAudioPlayer audio plays for about 1 second, and then the audio stops and the webview is restored. Is there a way to get the two to coexist peacefully?

**Edit**: Looks like this is the culprit, thanks again, Apple: 
[Setting AVAudioSession Category has no effect on sound from WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152211/setting-avaudiosession-category-has-no-effect-on-sound-from-wkwebview)
and 
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167788

Comment: Sweet! You found the answer. Put it in below so people can check it if they are looking

Comment: That's not an answer, it's a reason the problem exists.

Comment: If you’re using Xamarin.Forms don’t need to deal with any of that! You should try the brand new ‘MediaElement’ control on Xamarin forms. It makes adding videos a piece of cake. Check out the official docs for it over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/mediaelement

Comment: Unfortunately MediaElement doesn't help me since the underlying issue with WkWebView prevents WebRTC from sharing the AVAudioSession.